# Multivariate "base polynomials"

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

> Fix a positive integer $b$. For any positive integer $N$ whose base-$b$ expansion is $\sum \alpha_k b^k$, define $p_N(x)$ to be the polynomial $\sum\alpha_k x^k$.
>
> **Goal:** Produce a polynomial $\tilde p_N(x,y)$ such that
>
> - $\tilde p_N(x,1)=p_{p_N(1)}(x)$
> - $\tilde p_N(x,b)=p_N(x)$
> - all coefficients are in $\{0,1,\dots, b\}$
> - the polynomial is unique in some reasonable context

**Motivation:**

Recall that by the uniqueness of numbers' base-$b$ expansions, for any number $N$ there is a unique polynomial $p_N(x)$ with coefficients in $\{0,1,\dots, b-1\}$ such that $p_N(b)=N$.

I was interested in exploring the [digital sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigitSum.html) function $s_b$, and thought that considering polynomials might be a fruitful way to go about this, because given the "polynomialization" $p_N$ of the expansion above, we have that $s_b(N)=p_N(1)$.

However, my particular application was interested in iterating the digital sum function down to a single-digit number. For this, it is somewhat clunky to go from numbers to polynomials and back to numbers, and then iterate. What I would rather do is start with numbers, pass to polynomials, iterate, and then go back to numbers.

Unfortunately, a method for doing this does not appear so obvious to me, and I was wondering if any of you could shed some insight into a plausible construction. (I believe that if we can construct the 2-variable case from the 1-variable case, then I will be able to see what happens after that. But at this crucial step I am lost.)

Comment: I don't see where you have defined $p_{s_b(N)}(x)$.

Comment: @Gerry: Ah that is obnoxious. I originally wrote the post with the goal at the bottom but tried to move it up; the notation has gotten a little jumbled, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hopefully it is unambiguous now.